# Processing Character Strings into Numerical Variables in R

Tags: r

I've been trying to convert 538's poll 'grading' system (A+ to F- much like school grades) into a series of numbers using if-else statements and functions as outlined

[image: here].

I have also attempted using the `switch()` function, but nothing has worked.  Any thoughts on how to get this done?

Comment: *"but nothing has worked."* Please edit your post to include reproducible sample data and the code you've tried. Also include your expected output. Be specific, "nothing has worked" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Put your (short) sample code into the question instead of adding links to somewhere.

Comment: From the picture of your code, it seems like you are using `if{} else{}` when you need `ifelse()`. But since you're using `dplyr` already, look into `case_when`. See the examples at the bottom of `?case_when`

Comment: A `match` operation would be simpler, faster, and easier to maintain.

Comment: In the future, please consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to better formulate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option using `dplyr` is to use the `case_when` statement as follows:

```
df$Num_grade <- NA
df <- mutate(df, Num_grade = case_when(
   grades == 'A' ~ 13,
   grades == 'A-' ~ 12,
   grades == 'B+' ~ 11,
   .
   .
   .
   grades == 'F-' ~ 1
))
```

Wich works a lot like several ifelse statements, but easier to understand in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

It's cleaner to do a left join with a `lookup` `data.frame` that contains the mappings `grade` to `gradenumber`. That way you avoid the many `ifelse` statements.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
# Grades
grades <- paste0(rep(LETTERS[c(1:4,6)], each = 3), c("+", "", "-"))[-c(1, 13)]
grades
#[1] "A"  "A-" "B+" "B"  "B-" "C+" "C"  "C-" "D+" "D"  "D-" "F"  "F-"
```

Generate `lookup` `data.frame`

```
lookup <- data.frame(
    grade = grades,
    gradenumber = length(grades):1)
```

We now generate some sample data `PollsFiltered` and then `left_join` the data with `lookup` on `grade`.

```
set.seed(2018)
PollsFiltered <- data.frame(
    grade = sample(grades, 20, replace = T)
)

library(dplyr)
PollsFiltered %>%
    left_join(lookup, by = "grade")
#   grade gradenumber
#1     B-           9
#2      C           7
#3      A          13
#4     B+          11
#5      C           7
#6      B          10
#7     C-           6
#8     A-          12
#9     F-           1
#10    C-           6
#11    C+           8
#12    D+           5
#13    F-           1
#14    D+           5
#15    D-           3
#16    D+           5
#17     B          10
#18    C-           6
#19     D           4
#20    D-           3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `ifelse`, you could do the following:

```
df$numericGrade = NA
df$numericGrade[df$grade=="A"] = 13
df$numericGrade[df$grade=="A-"] = 12
df$numericGrade[df$grade=="B+"] = 11
df$numericGrade[df$grade=="C-"] = 6
```

For example:

```
df = data.frame(Name = c("John", "Mary", "Timmy", "Susan"), grade = c("B+", "A", "C-", "DNF"))

   Name grade
1  John    B+
2  Mary     A
3 Timmy    C-
4 Susan   DNF
```

applying the previous lines results in:

```
   Name grade numericGrade
1  John    B+           11
2  Mary     A           13
3 Timmy    C-            6
4 Susan   DNF           NA
```

Of course this takes one line for every case and my example is not complete.

#### Using Merge

Another option is to use `merge`.  In this case you need to have another data frame with the grades conversion:

```
gradesDict = data.frame(letter = c("A", "A-", "B+", "C-"),
                        number = c(13, 12, 11, 6))

  letter number
1      A     13
2     A-     12
3     B+     11
4     C-      6
```

and then do:

```
df = merge(df, gradesDict, by.x = "grade", by.y = "letter", all.x = T)

  grade  Name number
1     A  Mary     13
2    B+  John     11
3    C- Timmy      6
4   DNF Susan     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use `match` (building on the MCVE offered byt Maurits:

```
 grades <- paste0(rep(LETTERS[c(1:4,6)], each = 3), c("+", "", "-"))[-c( 13)] # keep A+
 PollsFiltered$nums <- match(PollsFiltered$grade, rev(grades) ) # F(1) to A+(14)

> head(PollsFiltered)
  grade nums
1     B   10
2    C+    8
3    A+   14
4    A-   12
5    C+    8
6     B   10
```